# App crashes when opening a class which contains a ListView

Tags: android, class, listview, forceclose

I have the following class which as you can see contains a EditText, Button and list.
I want the user to type in the EditText some text,click Search and Show up the results from

```
SQLite database in the list below the button/edittext field.
public class FindOrder  extends ListActivity {
private List<String> arr;
private ListView listView;
Button search;
EditText search_field;
String search_val;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.find_order);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("myTag","in func");
    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    search_field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);
    search.setOnClickListener(  
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    search_val=search_field.getText().toString();
                    //getOrder(search_val);

                }
            });
}

public void getOrder(String val) {
    Log.e("myTag","in func");
    String query;
    String[] s_arr = new String[1];
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    db =  this.openOrCreateDatabase( "DBname", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    query="SELECT OrderName, OrderLink, DateYear, DateMonth, DateDay, OrderPrice FROM Orders where OrderName=?";
    s_arr[0]=val;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, s_arr);
    if (c != null ) {
       if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
           do {     
               arr.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colName)));
               Log.e("myTag",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colName)));
           } while (c.moveToNext());
       }
   } 
   c.close();
  //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr));
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  TextView textview = new TextView(this);
  LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
  ll2.addView(textview);

}
}
```

Currently whenever i click on the button in Main Menu which leads to this activity, i get an FC.
One of the errors i can see i the log is :

```
06-02 10:32:18.387: E/AndroidRuntime(1904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Sagi.MyOrders/com.Sagi.MyOrders.FindOrder}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Together with many other errors . **But i couldn't really understand why should i have .list attribute ...**

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_field"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Thanks !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change this line in xml file where you declare listview.

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

No need to declare listview. Please try below code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Please check below example.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what should the following line get :
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(???)

Comment: remove that as you extend ListActivity.

Comment: Removed, no FC... but the List isn't showed up, the records are queried ... but nothing appears.

Comment: have you got values from cursor ? try to log that value.

Answer (score 1):

your listview id must be `android:id="@android:id/list"` when you extends `ListActivity` to your Activity.

```
           <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Tried it, if i change there i also have to change in the Java code and i get the same FC. The name in the XML shouldn't change since i treat it ...

Comment: I dont know if this already solved or not, but i may give opinion: do you unintentionally adding _import android.R_?

Answer (score 1):

change your list view id in xml file `android:id="@android:id/list"`

and in java code,

you have used `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView)`
change that to `listView = this.getListView()`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1:**
in xml file change the id of listview

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and also in you code change this line listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); as

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

**Solution2:**

Your activity must extend Activity instead of ListActivity.